# Code review with GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to perform code review (for your own projects) using GitLab? For instance automated reviews, but also manual review where you can comment and propose changes at a review of a commit?

Comment: This is remarkably vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Gitlab has the concept of [Discussions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/) (either single comments or discussion threads), which you can have on a variety of development items/activities, including the code itself (in which case they effectively are code reviews):

> The ability to contribute conversationally is offered throughout
>   GitLab.
>
> You can leave a comment in the following places:
>
> - issues
> - epics
> - merge requests
> - snippets
> - commits
> - commit diffs

But note that only merge request discussions are presently considered [resolvable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/#resolvable-comments-and-discussions).

Even though the check for a merge request can be configured to be automated, the starting of a review/discussion itself (if/when needed) is a manual operation. From [Threaded discussions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/#threaded-discussions):

> To start a threaded discussion, click on the **Comment** button toggle
>   dropdown, select **Start discussion** and click **Start discussion**
>   when you’re ready to post the comment.